# how to take input in c++ and check a text file and then output specific info

Tags: c++, project

I'm working on my school project that focuses on periodic table and hydrocarbons. I tried to do something different, so I made custom header files for each function and included them in the main program. I now want to use file handling concept too. so I decided to put all the element names along with symbols and their atomic numbers in a text file. I tried to access them with the help of user input atomic no and decided to set a pattern for it in the text file, first 3 spaces will either be numbers or space and then a space and then element name like :

```
1(space)(space)(space)Hydrogen(H)

:

20(space)(space)Calcium(Ca)

:



118(space)Oganesson(Og)
```

and this my header file pertaining to this specific program

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>

void ptablefunc()
{int a_no, s1, s2, p2, s3, p3, s4, d3, p4, s5, d4, p5, s6, f4, d5, p6, s7, f5, d6, p7;
int no[30];
char name[15];
textcolor(GREEN);
textbackground(BLACK);
clrscr();
randomize();

int k,l,m,n,o,p,q;

cout<<"\t\t\t       PERIODIC TABLE\n";
cout<<"\n     1___2___3___4___5___6___7___8___9__10__11__12__13__14__15__16__17__18_____\n";
cout<<" 1 | H |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | He|\n";
cout<<"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" 2 | li| Be|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  B| C | N | O | F | Ne|\n";
cout<<"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" 3 | Na| Mg|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | Al| Si| P | S | Cl| Ar|\n";
cout<<"   --------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" 4 | K | Ca| Sc| Ti| V | Cr| Mn| Fe| Co| Ni| Cu| Zn| Ga| Ge| As| Se| Br| Kr|\n";
cout<<"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" 5 | Rb| Sr| Y | Zr| Nb| Mo| Tc| Ru| Rh| Pd| Ag| Cd| In| Sn| Sb| Te| I | Xe|\n";
cout<<"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" 6 | Cs| Ba| * | Hf| Ta| W | Re| Os| Ir| Pt| Au| Hg| Tl| Pb| Bi| Po| At| Rn|\n";
cout<<"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" 7 | Fr| Ra| * | Rf| Db| Sg| Bh| Hs| Mt| Ds| Rg| Cn| Nh| Fl| Mc| Lv| Ts| Og|\n";
cout<<"   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------";
cout<<" \n * (Lanthanoid series) La Ce Pr Nd Pm Sm Eu Gd Tb Dy Ho Er Tm Yb Lu\n";
cout<<" ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<" *  (Actinoid series)  Ac Th Pa  U Np Pu Am Cm Bk Cf Es Fm Md No Lr\n";
cout<<"\n";
cout<<"\tEnter the atomic number of the element you want to search for:";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t    ->";
 cin>>a_no;
 clrscr();
 textbackground(BLACK);
 textcolor(RED+BLINK);
 clrscr();

  for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    cout<<endl;

   cout<<"\t\t\t\t   LOADING...";

     delay(2000);
      textcolor(GREEN);
      clrscr();
      cout<<"\n\n";
      cout<<"\t\t\t\t   ";
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifstream element;
element.open("table.txt",ios::in);

while(!element.eof())
{
cout<<no<<endl;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if(a_no>=1&&a_no<=118) //to print the atomic number of the given element
{
if (a_no<119)
cout<<endl<<"\n\nAtomic Number of element is "<<a_no<<endl<<endl;
}
delay(500);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if(a_no==1)//to find the atomic mass of the given element
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<a_no<<endl<<endl;
if (a_no>1 && a_no<22)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<2*a_no+random(2)<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>22 && a_no<32)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<2*a_no+random(3)+2<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>31 && a_no<38)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<2*a_no+random(5)+5<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>37 && a_no<46)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<2*a_no+random(5)+8<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>45 && a_no<58)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<2*a_no+random(8)+12<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>57 && a_no<72)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<(245*a_no)/100<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>71 && a_no<81)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<(25*a_no)/10<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>80 && a_no<103)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<(256*a_no)/100<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>102 && a_no<113)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<(254*a_no)/100<<endl<<endl;
else if (a_no>112 && a_no<119)
 cout<<"Atomic mass of element is "<<(251*a_no)/100<<endl<<endl;
delay(500);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (a_no==1)  //the shell configuration of the given element
 {k=1;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<endl<<endl;}
else if (a_no==2)
 {k=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<endl<<endl; }
else if (a_no>2 && a_no<11)
 {k=2;
 l=a_no-2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<endl<<endl;}
else if (a_no>=11 && a_no<19)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=a_no-10;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<endl<<endl;}
else if (a_no>=19 && a_no<21)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=8;
 n=a_no-18;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<endl<<endl;}
else if (a_no>=21 && a_no<29)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 n=2;
 m=a_no-12;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<endl<<endl;}
else if ((a_no>=29 && a_no<37) ||(a_no==46))
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=a_no-28;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<endl<<endl;}
else if (a_no==37 || a_no==38)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=8;
 o=a_no-36;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<endl<<endl;}
else if (a_no==39 || a_no==40 || a_no==43)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 o=2;
 n=a_no-30;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no==41 || a_no==42 || a_no==44 || a_no==45)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 o=1;
 n=a_no-29;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no>=47 && a_no<55)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=18;
 o=a_no-46;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no==55 || a_no==56)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=18;
 o=8;
 p=a_no-54;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no==57 || a_no==58 || a_no==64 || a_no==71)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=a_no-39;
 o=9;
 p=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<endl<<endl;}
else if((a_no>=59 && a_no<64) || (a_no>=65 && a_no<71))
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=a_no-38;
 o=8;
 p=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no>=72 && a_no<81)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=a_no-62;
 p=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no>=81 && a_no<87)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=18;
 p=a_no-78;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no==87 || a_no==88)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=18;
 p=8;
 q=a_no-86;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
else if((a_no>=97 && a_no<104) || a_no==94 || a_no==95)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=a_no-70;
 p=8;
 q=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no==90)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=18;
 p=10;
 q=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
else if((a_no>=91 && a_no<94) || a_no==89)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=a_no-71;
 p=9;
 q=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
else if((a_no>=104 && a_no<110) || a_no==112)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=32;
 p=a_no-94;
 q=2;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no==110 || a_no==111)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=32;
 p=a_no-93;
 q=1;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
else if(a_no>=113 && a_no<119)
 {k=2;
 l=8;
 m=18;
 n=32;
 o=32;
 p=18;
 q=a_no-110;
 cout<<"The shell configuration of the element is -> "<<"K-"<<k<<" L-"<<l<<" M-"<<m<<" N-"<<n<<" O-"<<o<<" P-"<<p<<" Q-"<<q<<endl<<endl;}
delay(500);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     //to find the electronic configuration of the element
cout<<"The electronic configuration of the element is : \n";
         if (a_no<=2)
      s1=a_no;
     else if (a_no>2)
        s1=2;

     if (a_no<=4 && a_no>=2)
      s2=a_no-2;
     else if (a_no<2)
      s2=0;
     else
      if (a_no>4)
        s2=2;

     if (a_no<=10 && a_no>=4)
        p2=(a_no-4);
     else if (a_no<4)
        p2=0;
     else
        if (a_no>10)
        p2=6 ;

     if (a_no<=12 && a_no>=10)
        s3=a_no-10;
     else if (a_no<10)
        s3=0;
     else
        if (a_no>12)
        s3=2;

     if (a_no<=18 && a_no>=12)
        p3=a_no-12;
     else if (a_no<12)
        p3=0;
     else
        if (a_no>18)
        p3=6;

     if (a_no<=20 && a_no>=18)
        s4=a_no-18;
     else if (a_no<18)
         s4=0;
     else
        if(a_no>20)
        s4=2;

     if (a_no<=30 && a_no>=20)
        d3=a_no-20;
     else if (a_no<20)
        d3=0;
     else
        if (a_no>30)
        d3=10;

     if (a_no<=36 && a_no>=30)
        p4=a_no-30;
     else if (a_no<30)
        p4=0;
     else
        if(a_no>36)
        p4=6;

     if (a_no<=38 && a_no>=36)
        s5=a_no-36;
     else if (a_no<36 || a_no==46 )
        s5=0;
     else
        if((a_no>38 && a_no<41)|| a_no>47 || a_no==43)
        s5=2;
     else
        if((a_no>40 && a_no<46)|| a_no==48)
        s5=1;

     if ((a_no<=40 && a_no>=38)||a_no==43)
        d4=a_no-38;
     else if ((a_no>=41 && a_no<=45)||a_no==47)
        d4=a_no-37;
     else if (a_no<38)
        d4=0;
     else
        d4=10;

     if (a_no<=54 && a_no>=48)
        p5=a_no-48;
     else if (a_no<48)
        p5=0;
     else
        if (a_no>54)
        p5=6;

     if (a_no<=56 && a_no>=54)
        s6=a_no-54;
     else if (a_no<54)
        s6=0;
     else
        if (a_no>56)
        s6=2;
     if (a_no<=70 &&  a_no>=56)
        f4=a_no-56;
     else if (a_no<56)
        f4=0;
     else
        if(a_no>70)
        f4=14;

     if (a_no<=80 && a_no>=70)
        d5=a_no-70;
     else if (a_no<70)
        d5=0;
     else
        if (a_no>80)
        d5=10;

     if (a_no<=86 && a_no>=80)
        p6=a_no-80;
     else if (a_no<80)
        p6=0;
     else
        p6=6;

     if (a_no<=88 && a_no>=86)
        s7=a_no-86;
     else if (a_no<86)
        s7=0;
     else
        if(a_no>88)
        s7=2;

     if(a_no<=102 && a_no>=88)
        f5=a_no-88;
     else if (a_no<88)
        f5=0;
     else
        if (a_no>102)
        f5=14;

     if (a_no<=112 && a_no>=102)
        d6=a_no-102;
     else if (a_no<102)
        d6=0;
     else
         if(a_no>112)
         d6=10;

     if (a_no<=118 && a_no>=112)
        p7=a_no-112;

     else if (a_no<112)
        p7=0;
     else
        if (a_no>118)
        p7=6;

        cout<<"\n 1s: "<<s1<<"\n 2s: "<<s2<<" 2p: "<<p2<<"\n 3s: "<<s3<<" 3p: "<<p3<<" 3d: "<<d3;
        cout<<"\n 4s: "<<s4<<" 4p: "<<p4<<" 4d: "<<d4<<" 4f: "<<f4<<"\n 5s: "<<s5<<" 5p: "<<p5<<" 5d: "<<d5<<" 5f: "<<f5;
        cout<<"\n 6s: "<<s6<<" 6p: "<<p6<<" 6d: "<<d6<<"\n 7s: "<<s7<<"\n 7p: "<<p7; 
delay(500);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout<<"\n\n Valency : ";  //finding the valency of the given element
int v;
if(a_no==1 || a_no==2)
{ v=2-a_no;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>2 && a_no<7)
{ v=a_no-2;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>6 && a_no<11)
{ v=6-p2;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>10 && a_no<17)
{ v=a_no-10;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>16 && a_no<25)
{ v=fabs(a_no-18);
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no==28||a_no==29||a_no==36)
{ v=2;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=30 && a_no<=35)
{ v=a_no-28;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=37 && a_no<=43)
{ v=a_no-36;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=47 && a_no<=53)
{ v=a_no-46;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=55 && a_no<=58)
{ v=a_no-54;
 cout<<v;}
else if((a_no>=60 && a_no<=70) || a_no==26 ||(a_no>=100 && a_no<=102))
{ v=3;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=71 && a_no<=75)
{ v=a_no-68;
 cout<<v;}
else if((a_no>=76&&a_no<=79)||a_no==86||a_no==93||a_no==94||a_no==44||a_no==45||a_no==54)
{ v=6;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=80 && a_no<=85)
{ v=a_no-78;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=87 && a_no<=92)
{ v=a_no-86;
 cout<<v;}
else if((a_no>=95 && a_no<=99)||a_no==59||a_no==46||a_no==25||a_no==27)
{ v=4;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=103 && a_no<=107)
{ v=a_no-100;
 cout<<v;}
else if(a_no>=108 && a_no<=118)
{cout<<"not found yet";}
delay(500);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout<<"\n\nRadioactivity status: ";  //to find out the radioactive element
if (a_no==43 || a_no==61 || (a_no>=84 && a_no<119))
 cout<<"The element is radioactive. "<<endl<<endl;
else
 cout<<"The element is not radioactive. "<<endl<<endl;
 getch();     
}
```

I just need to know how do I check whether a_no matches with the atomic number in the file and if it matches, how do I output just the name from the line in which they match?

Comment: Sorry but facebook is really not the platform to share code. Put the relevant piece of code here and specify your question more.

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste your code into the web page.  Then select your code and press the {} button at the top of the editor window.

Comment: what JozefLegény said. "sorry I'm not able to post the code here" why? You need to post the relevant code here. Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: I think the problem is there are way too many lines of code for a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to 'tokenise' a string and there is a function to do this in the C libraries called `strtok()`.  It takes an input string (your line) and returns the next string until it sees the character you specify is the delimiter, in this case space.

```
char* token = strtok(line, delimiter);
while (token) // is not null
{
    printf("The next token is %s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
```

`strtok` will ignore consecutive delimiters, so there is no difference between 3,2 or 1 spaces.

(Spaces are not a good character to use as a delimiter, because they can occur in words.  You should be OK for this code, but when you come to peoples names use stars or something.)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you to do is to write all this info you are manually checking while your code is running, into a proper serializable file in f.e. JSON or XML format and then just use some C++ library to read the format into your program.

Here is a JSON example of how the structure of this file could look like:

```
{
    "19" : {
        "name" : "Blahium",
        "shortName" : "BL",
        "mass" : 2,
        "shellConfig" : {
            "K" : 2,
            "L" : 8,
            "M" : 8,
            "N" : 1
        },
        "electronicConfig" : {
            "s1" : 12,
            "p4" : 25
        }
    },
    "20" : {
       // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

And the library you could use to read this JSON data could be [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which is pretty easy to use.

And then in your code you would just load that JSON, read the data, and print it. So for example, for the shell configuration part, instead of having these 300 hundred lines of if else statements and duplicated code, you would jst have something like this:

```
// nlohmann::json data is the above file serialized by the json library
void printElectronicConfiguration(nlohman::json data, int atomicNumber) {
    auto item = data.find(atomicNumber);
    if (item == data.end()) 
        return; // return if element with that number wasn't found

    cout << "The shell configuration of the element is -> ";
    if (item["K"] != 0)
        cout << "K-" << item["K"];
    // etc
    cout << endl;
}
```

I'm sorry if the examples aren't clear enough, but from those 600+ lines of code you provided, it is hard to pull out important information and how this data scheme should look like.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about it but unfortunately i cant use JSON and XML files as it is not in my syllabus.